# (Regex) how to retrieve the contents of a particular div (p, span, etc) by ignoring the HTML it contains, using Python

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup, html-parser

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNkCS.png)

**Hello stackoverflow family**

Elements to select its element of which I want to recover.
the goal here is of recuper all the contents of a quelquonque beacon are unaware of it code HTML which contien

```html
My regex is  ((<p)([\s]+|([a-zA-Z=(\"|')_[\s]+|]+)([\s]+|)>)|<p>)([a-zA-Z ]+)<

<ol class="arabic">
  <li>
    <div class="first">
      Start the notebook server from the
      <a class="reference internal" href="glossary">
        <span class="xref std std-term">command line</span>
      </a>
      : yes very good
    </div>

    <div class="highlight-default notranslate">
      The notebook open in your browse.
      <span>ok very good</span>
      <span class="n">ok nice</span>
      <span class="n">notebook</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNkCS.png I'm going to retrieve the selector element in the code, but I can get a regex able to parse code